# Where can I find tutorials about ant properties?

Tags: java, ant, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to learn some ant for a Struts 1.x project that I was thrown onto.  Mainly I'm trying to find a good referent for the inherent variables/properties of ant...beginners tutorial.  Any GOOD reference really.

A couple lines of the ant file that I've been trying to figure out just for example...

```
<available file=${deploy.ant.docbase.dir}/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml" property="sun.web.present"/>
```

and

```
<replace file="${temp.sun.web}">
    <replacetoken><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE]]></replacetoken>
    <replacevalue<![CDATA[<!-- <!DOCTYPE]]></replacevalue> //in ant is <!-- the comment out flag?
</replace>
```

I did do some searching and only could find ant build examples without explanation, but if it is covered and I just didn't find it a link will suffice.  No reason to make someone reexplain it....I just couldn't find it.

Comment: The example you show doesn't use a built-in property.  Most Ant targets won't, because after properties are first set they are  immutable.  Instead, Ant scripts usually define their own properties.  The Ant manual (see answer below for link) lists the properties that Ant will predefine.

Comment: If you want to get into the guts of Ant, I recommend the Manning "Ant in Action" book.

Comment: Are looking at a file named ant-deploy.xml in a directory named nbproject?

Comment: @bithead61 I really wish you would have posted your responses as a response to the question so I could accept it.  You have answered my main question best!  While I have reviewed the ant manual I don't like how it reads....so far I prefer the ant in action book!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code block refers to the ["available" ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html). It sets the property sun.web.present if the given file exists.

In your second code block, "<!--" starts an XML comment ("-->" closes one). This is true for all XML, not just ant build.xml files. In this case it is using the ["replace" ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) to replace "<!DOCTYPE" with "<!-- <!DOCTYPE" within the file named by temp.sun.web.

In general an ant build file has targets like "build" or "clean". These depend on each other so that "test" runs "build" first. The targets are implemented by "tasks", where each XML tag refers to a task. You can [read their manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) and refer to the per-task docs for how each task works.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) is your friend. There's a link *Ant tasks* on the left side of the page. Click on that link, and then the *List of Tasks* link. That will list all of the Ant tasks on the left and their explanation on the right. There, you'll see the `available` task and the `replace` task.

Unfortunately, the Ant manual uses Frames (bad Ant Manual! Bad Ant Manual!), so I can't supply a link that will list both the

Answer (score 2):

*(Shameless bid for reputation)*

The example doesn't use a built-in property. Most Ant targets won't, because after properties are first set they are immutable. Instead, Ant scripts usually define their own properties. The Ant manual lists the properties that Ant predefines.

If you want to get into the guts of Ant, I recommend the Manning "Ant in Action" book.